# Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar is missing

Tags: spring-cloud

I'm developing code from the link: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config-server-git/ and when I updated the **Spring Boot** version **2.1.2.RELEASE** pom.xml is giving me below error.

> Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar is missing.

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: please show your full configuration

Comment: Newbie here - wouldn't it be the case to explicitly add the       `<version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>` tag beneath the artifactId?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is to add a property to define the version of all your spring-cloud dependencies like this:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

and next add this dependency managment:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>  
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```